# I built gstreamer plugin in VS-windows. But on gst-inspect-1.0 :: Could not load plugin file: File "GstPluginTemplate.dll" is not a GStreamer plugin

Tags: plugins, gstreamer

I am trying to build a gstreamer plugin template. For this VS project [GstPluginTemplate], I included files : gstplugin.c and gstplugin.h from https://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-template/tree/gst-plugin/src
It got built in VS'19 as a dll.

Then,in cmd prompt, I navigated to the Debug folder which has the GstPluginTemplate.dll and did gst-inspect-1.0 .
I am getting the following error :

```
C:\GstPluginTemplate\x64\Debug>gst-inspect-1.0 GstPluginTemplate.dll --gst-plugin-path=.
Could not load plugin file: File "GstPluginTemplate.dll" is not a GStreamer plugin
```

Can someone guide me on what step/code am I missing out on ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

The name defined in the 3rd argument of GST_PLUGIN_DEFINE and
the target name of the project properties have to be same.
[image]